# How to pass filter value from URL after rebuilding url with the goal of implementing infinite scroll using Angular2 and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a search page where you can search books and apply several filters. On allpying filter I am sending the request in the URL to server. I have implemented that using the following javascript ->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var base_url = 'https://'+window.location.hostname;
var url = base_url+'/books/search/';
var next_url = base_url+'/books/search/next/';
var filter_url = base_url+'/books/search/filter/';
var search_input = $('.search-bar input');

var bookSeach = {

    searchQueryAsString : function(el){
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        var id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('_')+1)
        var filter_type = $(el).closest('ul.p-search-var-items').attr('filter-type')
        var name = $(el).val();
        $('#'+filter_type+'_id').val(id)
        $('#'+filter_type+'_name').val(name)
        return this.buildSearchQuery()
    },

    searchQueryAsArray : function(el){

        el.find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            var filter=$(this).closest('.p-search-var-items').attr('filter-type')
            var id = $(this).attr('id')
            var name = $(this).val()
            id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('_')+1)
            var value = $('#'+filter+'_id').val()!='' ?$('#'+filter+'_id').val()+','+id : id
            $('#'+filter+'_id').val(value)
            var nvalue = $('#'+filter+'_name').val()!='' ?$('#'+filter+'_name').val()+','+name : name
            $('#'+filter+'_name').val(nvalue)
        })
        return this.buildSearchQuery()
    },

    buildSearchQuery : function(){
        var self = this;
        var query_url = base_url+'/books/search/';
        $('input.filter_value').each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            if(el.val()!=''){
                value = $.trim(el.val())
                query_url = self.updateQueryStringParameter(query_url,el.attr('id'),value)
                next_url = self.updateQueryStringParameter(next_url,el.attr('id'),value)
                filter_url = self.updateQueryStringParameter(filter_url,el.attr('id'),value)
            }
        })
        return {'url':query_url,'next_url':next_url,'filter_url':filter_url};
    },

    updateQueryStringParameter : function(uri, key, value) {
      var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
      var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
      if (uri.match(re)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
      }
      else {
        return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
      }
    },

    filterText : function (elem) {
        var value = elem.val().toLowerCase();
        var filter = elem.attr('data-filter')
        $(".p-search-var-items[filter-type='"+filter+"'] > li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    },

    loadBooksOnScroll : function(count){
        var ajax_url = bookSeach.buildSearchQuery()
        if($('#dropdownMenu1').attr('data-filter-applied')!=''){
            ajax_url = ajax_url['filter_url']
            data = {'index':count,'type':$('#dropdownMenu1').attr('data-filter-applied')}
        }else{
            ajax_url = ajax_url['next_url']
            data = {'index':count}

        }
        this.ajaxHandler(ajax_url,'GET',data,this.renderBookList)
    },
    loadBooksOnSort : function(type){
        var ajax_url = bookSeach.buildSearchQuery()
        ajax_url = ajax_url['filter_url']
        this.ajaxHandler(ajax_url,'GET',{'index':0,'type':type},function(response){
            $('.p-result').html('')
            bookSeach.renderBookList(response)
        })
    },
    ajaxHandler : function(url,method,data,callback){
        $.ajax({
            'url':url,
            'type':method,
            'data':data,
            'success':function(response){
                if(response){
                    callback(response)
                }
            }
        })
    },

    filterContentByKeyWord: function(key,type){
        var keyword = {}
        keyword[type+'_key']=key
        var ajax_url = base_url+'/'+type+'s/search/';
        this.ajaxHandler(ajax_url,'GET',keyword,function(result){
            bookSeach.renderFilterContent(result,type)
        })
    },

    renderFilterContent: function(results,type){
        $('.'+type+'-results').html('')
        var template =_.template($('#'+type+'_template').html())
        var id = this.getUrlParameter(type+'_id')
        console.log(id, results,id)
        $('.'+type+'-results').append(template({'results':results,'id':id}))
    },

    renderBookList : function(books){
        var template =_.template($('#book_detail').html())
        $('.p-result').append(template({'books':books}))
    },

    removeParameter : function(url, parameter){

      var urlparts= url.split('?');

      if (urlparts.length>=2)
      {
          var urlBase=urlparts.shift(); //get first part, and remove from array
          var queryString=urlparts.join("?"); //join it back up

          var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
          var pars = queryString.split(/[&;]/g);
          for (var i= pars.length; i-->0;)
              if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0)!==-1)   //idiom for string.startsWith
                  pars.splice(i, 1);
          url = urlBase+'?'+pars.join('&');
      }
      return url;
    },

    getUrlParameter : function(sParam){
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

};

// Search within filters by keyword - START

//Delay function to prevent calling the function on every key press
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

//On keyup for search within filters
$('.p-search-cat-box').on('keyup',function(){
    var self = this
    delay(function(){
        var filter = $(self).attr('data-filter');
        if(filter=='author' || filter=='publisher' || filter=='seller' || filter=='institute'){
            $('#'+filter+'_key').val($(self).val())
            bookSeach.filterContentByKeyWord($(self).val(),filter)
        }else{
            bookSeach.filterText($(self))
        }
    }, 600 )

});

// Search within filters by keyword - END


//Filters on change event  - START

// For category and sub category
$('.p-search-var-items input:radio').on('change',function(){
    var redirect_url = bookSeach.searchQueryAsString($(this))
    window.location.href = redirect_url['url'];
})

// For Authors, Publishers and Binding
$(document).on('change','.p-search-var-items input:checkbox',function(){
    elem = $(this)
    el = elem.closest('.p-search-var-items')
    $('#'+el.attr('filter-type')+'_id').val('')
    $('#'+el.attr('filter-type')+'_name').val('')
    var redirect_url = bookSeach.searchQueryAsArray(elem.closest('.p-search-cat-list'))
    window.location.href = redirect_url['url'];
})

//Filters on change event  - END

// Filters - collapse up and down - START

$('.filter-container .p-sub-cat i').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('fa-minus')){
        $(this).closest('.filter-container').find('.p-search-cat').hide("slide",{direction:'up'},500)
        $(this).removeClass('fa-minus')
        $(this).addClass('fa-plus')
    }else{
        $(this).closest('.filter-container').find('.p-search-cat').show("slide",{direction:'up'},500)
        $(this).removeClass('fa-plus')
        $(this).addClass('fa-minus')
    }

})

// Filters - collapse up and down - END


//Search box Header - START

$('#search_books').on('click',function(){
    var redirect_url = bookSeach.buildSearchQuery()
    window.location.href = redirect_url['url'];
})

$("#query").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#search_books").trigger('click');
    }
});

//Search box Header - END

//Applied FIlters - remove option

$('.p-filter-title img').on('click',function(){
    var param = $(this).attr('data-applied-filter')
    if(param=='author' || param=='publisher' || param=='seller' || param=='institute' || param=='binding' ){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-filter-id')
        $('#'+param+'_'+id).removeAttr('checked')
        $('#'+param+'_'+id).trigger('change')
    }else{
        var paramname = param.substr(0,param.lastIndexOf('_')+1)
        url = bookSeach.removeParameter(window.location.href,paramname+'name')
        redirect_url = bookSeach.removeParameter(url,param)
        window.location.href = redirect_url
    }

})



//Infinite Scroll - Book Results - START
if(location.href.indexOf('books/search/')>0){
    var count =10;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           bookSeach.loadBooksOnScroll(count);
           count+=10;
        }
    });

}

//Infinite Scroll - Book Results - END


//Filters in Responsive Layout - START

$('.apply').on('click',function(){
    $('.mobile-filters ul.p-search-var-items span.m_apply_filter').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-is-selected')=='true'){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            var type = $(this).attr('data-type')
            var value = $('#m_'+type+'_id').val()!=''? $('#m_'+type+'_id').val()+','+id : id
            $('#m_'+type+'_id').val(value)
        }
    })

    $('.m_filter').each(function(){
        var param = $(this).attr('id');
        param = param.substr(param.indexOf('m_')+2)
        value = $.trim($(this).val())
        redirect_url = bookSeach.updateQueryStringParameter(url,param,value)
    })
    window.location.href = redirect_url
})

$('.m_apply_filter').on('click',function(){

    if($(this).attr('data-is-selected')=='false'){
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('p-search-var-items-active')
        $(this).attr('data-is-selected','true')
    }else{
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('p-search-var-items-active')

        $(this).attr('data-is-selected','false')
    }

})

//Filters in Responsive Layout - END

$('.back-to-top').on('click', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0   )
})

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>1200){

      $('.back-to-top').removeClass('hide')
    }else{
      $('.back-to-top').addClass('hide')

    }
})

$('.presentation a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var type= $(this).data('type')
    bookSeach.loadBooksOnSort(type)
    $('#dropdownMenu1 .sort_filter').text('Sort by :'+type)
    $('#dropdownMenu1').attr('data-filter-applied',type)
})

   }

})

})
```

What it does is when you select a filters it changes the url makes a server call and displays the data accordingly.

It also implements infinite scroll on scrolling down it loads 10 more results.

I want to implement the entire thing using Angular2 with typescript. Can someone please suggest me how to implement my js code using typescritp and Angular2. I am new to angular so I am having some problem in implementing the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question instead of just linking to an external resource.

Comment: Actually it was a large block of code so I thought it would be better to use a paste bin . I will edit my question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an advise than answer. You should avoid using jQuery in Angular. The reason being jQuery modifies the DOM directly and Angular modifies the DOM via an abstraction. You'll run into a lot of trouble doing so.

I couldn't be stuff reading through all that, it's a big mess and doesn't look like you're doing it the proper way anyways and your methods are big and fat and noisy.

If your aim is after scrolling to a certain length then query and display more data then you can try something like:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', []) onWindowScroll($event: any) {
    // your logic...
}
```

Then in your template use `*ngIf`etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm too very new to angular 2 but this tutorial helped me a lot:
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-2-getting-started
further to implement infinite scroll use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll.
hope this helps :)

Comment: Although the links probably provide useful information, please include in your answer the parts that are relevant for the question: links can break.